# Displaying from Nodejs ExpressJS route to EJS view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I render the calc.ejs from calc.js router like this:

```
// calc.js router
router.get('/calc', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('calc', {page:'Calculator', menuId:'Calculator', result: ''});
});
```

My calc.ejs is :

```
// calc.ejs view
<form action="/user/calc" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="num1"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="num2"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>   

<% if( result ){ %>
    <p> Display result here!!! :  < %= result %> </p>
  <% } else{ %>  
    <h1>No Result</h1>
 <% } %>
```

And I have my calc.js controller which takes two numbers, calculates and returns them as json, but I want to display the result in the paragraph element in calc.ejs

```
// calc.js controller
exports.calc = (req, res, next) => {
    let rezz = Number(req.body.num1) + Number(req.body.num2)   

    res.status(200).json({
      result: rezz
    });
 }
```

I get this json  :

```
{"result":46}
```

My question is why the result doesn't display in  `<p>` element but comes as json, and how to display it there..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ejs :

```
< %= result %>  // this is wrong
<%= result %>   // this is right
```

In your controller, you can direct render your view and it should be:

```
exports.calc = (req, res, next) => {
    let rezz = Number(req.body.num1) + Number(req.body.num2) 
    res.render('calc',{
        page:'Calculator', 
        menuId:'Calculator',
        result: rezz
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can again render view in calc function

```
exports.calc = (req, res, next) => {
    let rezz = Number(req.body.num1) + Number(req.body.num2)   
     return res.render('calc', {page:'Calculator', menuId:'Calculator', result: rezz });
 }
```

if you want to use json then you have to call ajax function on form submit and send request and display returned response in view